# How can I get the Xpath location from a webelement

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to search a webpage for a certain text value and then to store this location as an xpath so that I can revisit this webpage to see has this text value changed.

The idea I have is using selenium webelement I would search through all the elements on the page for the text value. Then once I have it I would like to extract the location of this element.

Then I can revisit this page using the location previously stored to check the latest text value.

I was thinking of something like this...

```
java.util.List<WebElement> els = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));

for ( WebElement el : els ) {
    if (el.getText().contains("some text")){
        //store el.xpath
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I want this to work on any random webpage so obviously the xpath reference would be different for different webpages. The key for me is to find out is it possible to extract or create an xpath reference from the webelement I initially find via the getText method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with pseudo java code, looping the css locator list like this:

```
By sub-locator = By.xpath(".//*[contains(.,'some text')]");
for ( WebElement el : els ) {
    By storableLocator = new ByChained(el, sub-locator);
    if ( storableLocator is visible )
    {
        //store storableLocator
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks djangofan for your reply. As I'm quite new to java can you tell me what you mean by 'sub-locator'. and also, you mention to use e.xpath to get the xpath, do you mean el.xpath? If so I don't see an option for xpath from the webelement?

Comment: I updated the code snippet. I hope that answers your question.  Also, the ByChained locator can contain multiple locators chained together.  The first one, i call the baselocator, the second one I called sub-locator.

Comment: Are "sub-locator"  and "storableLocator" actual java classes?

Comment: No, they are instances of the By.class .

Comment: Ah ok, I get you. Thanks for that!!